# Como obter o id da conexão de um socket em um servidor node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, servidor, socket, socket.io

Olá, estou estudando sockets com node js para jogos e gostaria de saber como recuperar o id de uma conexão via socket de um cliente com o servidor, já tentei de varias formas mas não obtive sucesso!

**Meu código do cliente é o seguinte:**

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket(); //Cria o socket do cliente
client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() { //Inicia o socket do cliente
    console.log('Conectado ao servidor');
    client.write('Olá servidor! De, Cliente.');
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Recebido: ' + data);
});
```

**Meu codigo do servidor é o seguinte:**

```
var net     = require("net"); //Importa a biblioteca
var porta   = 3000; //Define qual porta o servidor vai escutar
var host    = "127.0.0.1";
var servidor = net.createServer(); //Cria o socket do servidor
servidor.listen(porta, function (socket){  //Roda o servidor
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado..`);
});
servidor.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(`Nova coneção`);
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(`Recebido: ` + data);
    })
});
```

Como eu posso obter o id da conexão/socket do cliente para ter um controle no meu servidor?

Meu código está bem simples, sei bem pouco e, estou apenas estudando como funciona os sockets no node, se tiverem sugestões de melhoras ou criticas estou totalmente aberto a recebe-las!!

Answer (score 3):

De maneira geral não existe o conceito de "id da conexão" no protocolo TCP. É possível saber o endereço IP e a porta de quem se conectou remotamente, no seu exemplo acimas eria através das propriedades socket.remoteAddress e socket.remotePort. No entanto isso não serve como "id da conexão", pois não tem unicidade garantida.

A solução geral deste problema está no escopo da aplicação, isto é, é preciso desenhar um "protocolo de aplicação", que na prática é simplesmente os formatos das mensagens que o seu server e o seu client entendem. Por exemplo, os 3 primeiros bytes podem identificar a operação que o client está pedindo ao server ("000" read, "001" write, etc). Uma destas operações poderia ser a "identificação" do client, por exemplo, operação "009", em seguida 5 dígitos com a identificação do client. Este é só um exemplo ilustrativo, as mensagens que o client e o server usam para conversar são de total controle de quem desenvolve a aplicação. Não precisam ser usados números, enfim, o programador tem total liberdade para escolher o formato das mensagens, para o protocolo TCP isso é irrelevante.

Agora, falando especificamente do seu exemplo e do node.js, o objeto "socket" que o evento "connect" fornece pode ser usado como identificador único da conexão, considerando uma única execução do server.

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu sistema utiliza alguma forma de login provavel que tenhas algum identificador unico.

Podes passar ele do cliente para o socket no servidor verificar e caso seja válido atribuir ao objeto de socket, exemplo:

```js
// client
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
var clientID = "xxxxx-yyyy";
client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    client.write(clientID);
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Recebido: ' + data);
});

// server
var net     = require("net");
var porta   = 3000;
var host    = "127.0.0.1";
var servidor = net.createServer();
servidor.listen(porta, function (socket){
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado..`);
});
servidor.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        // primeira conexão? checar...
        if ( !socket.id ) {
            // na primeira conexão o id será verificado
            var clientID = data
            // checar?
            if ( checkID(clientID) ) {
                socket.id = clientID
            } else {
                // derrubar connexão?
            }
         }
    })
});
```

Isso abre a possíbilidade de alguém tentar burlar um id no frontend ... talvez seja mais recomendado usar tokens `JWT` para passar ids.

Agora se a conexão não necessáriamente precisa seguir uma autenticação podes simplesmente adicionar (gerar) um id usando alguma biblioteca de **"uuid"**, exemplo:

```js
// server
var net     = require("net");
var uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1'); // biblioteca uuid (v1)
var porta   = 3000;
var host    = "127.0.0.1";
var servidor = net.createServer();
servidor.listen(porta, function (socket){
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado..`);
});
servidor.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        // primeira conexão? checar...
        if ( !socket.id ) {
            // a cada conexão a propriedade id será verificada
            socket.id = uuidv1();
         }
    })
});
```

---

**Referencias:**

- **[SO: how-to-uniquely-identify-a-socket-with-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805432/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-socket-with-node-js)**
- **[biblioteca uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)**